# Can't get pagination to work with this WP_Query loop

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I know pagination isn't as straight forward with WP_Query as it is with other loop types but normally I don't have a problem with it.

I'm editing a site for a client and this is their current loop;

```
<?php
    $temp_post = $post;
    $args = array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => 'project'            
    );
    $projects = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($projects->have_posts()) : $projects->the_post();
?>

    <!-- loop content -->

<?php
    endwhile;
    kriesi_pagination();
    $post = $temp_post;
?>
```

I tried my usual method of using `$wp_query` instead of `$portfolio` but that didn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `page` or `paged` argument to your `WP_Query`. Take a look at [WP_Query Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Pagination_Parameters).